# Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML using Context in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

This seems to be a fairly common question but the others seem to deal only with `useState`.

I have a simple shopping cart system using Context and `useReducer`. I've added the functionality to store the cart in cookies (with `js-cookie`) so the cart persists after refresh. However, when I refresh the page, the classic `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.` is triggered.

Getting initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  darkMode: false,
  cart: {
    cartItems: Cookies.get("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(Cookies.get("cartItems"))
      : [],
  },
};
```

Adding to cookies:

```
case "CART_ADD_ITEM": {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const cartItems = [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];
      Cookies.set("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }
```

Displaying the cart size in a simple tag for now:

```
<nav className="w-full h-12 bg-gray-100">
        Navbar | {cart.cartItems.length > 0 ? cart.cartItems.length : 0}
      </nav>
```

Solutions seem to revolve around using `useEffect` but I'm not sure how to implement that here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with `useEffect` - assigned the stored value to state variable and then checked it with useEffect

```
const [cartSize, setCartsize] = useState(0);

const cartSizeStore = cart.cartItems.length;

useEffect(() => {
  setCartsize(cartSizeStore);
}, [cartSizeStore]);
```