# Next.js throws error "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created fresh Next.js project and only added really simple component:

```
const IdPanel = () => {
  const [id] = useState(`${Math.random()}`);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id={id} className={id}>
        {id}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I run the dev server it throw an error in my browser "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML".

What's the solution to fix it?

Versions:

```
"next": "13.0.3",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0"
```

Comment: That's because when your component renders on the server, the `id` is different from the `id` when you component runs on the browser.

Comment: @vighnesh153 how do i fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837303/nextjs-hydration-errors-text-content-does-not-match-server-rendered-html

Comment: A simple solution would be to generate the dynamic data in a `useEffect`. Another reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121889/error-text-content-does-not-match-server-rendered-html-using-context-in-nextjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests, `id` on the server doesn't match the `id` on the client.

**EDIT:**
Simplest method is to have `useState` and then set the state in the `useEffect`

Other methods:

You can use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` to generate the random id, and then send it to the client.

In the first case, the page will be generated only once when the server starts. So when ever you try to access that page you will get the same result, because it has generated static HTML and `id` wont change.

In the other case the page will be generated on the server for every request to get that page. So you should get the different `id` each time.

Comment: Another approach would be to generate the id out of the component (alternative to getStaticProps).

Comment: Thanks for the really clear answer. Also I found another solution which you can add to your comment. You can import the component dynamically with Next.js dynamic function and set ssr to false in config so your component would only run client side. `dynamic(import('./idPanel'), { ssr: false })`.

Comment: This probably solves your initial problem, but i wouldn't recommend this option because it should be used when you specifically want for a component to be lazy loaded. I **wouldn't** even recommend `Other methods` from my answer because those too are used only in specific situations when you want to use SSG or SSR.